# Can you dynamically change window size of macos app built with SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm building an app for MacOS. The functionality requires the window to increase in size in certain situations and to scale back outside of these situations. Is this possible? any pointers or examples are appreciated

Comment: _"The functionality requires the window to increase in size in certain situations and to scale back outside of these situations."_ - please elaborate

Comment: So if someone presses a button, the window size should increase to accommodate the content. Once the user presses `escape`, the content will disappear so the window should go back to its original size

Comment: May be you could show us the attempts you made and where you are stuck. If you are totally lost, you could start with frame, button and a variable

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible by updating the frame of the `NSWindow` for your application, using `setFrame`. This method allows for setting the new frame (position and size) with and/or without animation.

Without animation (see [setFrame(NSRect, display: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419753-setframe))

```swift
window.setFrame(newFrame, display: true)
```

With animation (see [setFrame(NSRect, display: Bool, animate: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419519-setframe))

```swift
window.setFrame(newFrame, display: true, animated: true)
```

Calling any of these two methods will update the window of your application to whatever new frame you pass, including position and size.

The tricky part in SwiftUI is to get a hold to the `NSWindow`, since it is not trivial. Here is the TLDR:

1. Create a `NSViewRepresentable` to access the backing window:

```swift
struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var window: NSWindow?

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = view.window
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

The window is set in the next run loop using dispatch async, since it would be `nil` beforehand.

2. Add a `window` property to your SwiftUI view, and use the window accessor with a background modifier.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var window: NSWindow?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          // Your view content. Note: window might be nil until set
        }
        .background(WindowAccessor(window: $window))
        .onChange(of: window) {
          // This method will get called once when the window is set
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Window access:

```
NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?
```

And then, as [Eneko Alonso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425793/18030070) said:

> Without animation (see [setFrame(NSRect, display: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419753-setframe))
>
> ```
> window.setFrame(newFrame, display: true)
> ```
>
> With animation (see [setFrame(NSRect, display: Bool, animate: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419519-setframe))
>
> ```
> window.setFrame(newFrame, display: true, animated: true)
> ```

Eneko's answer only works if you only have one window. If you open the window separately and close it again, a memory leak is caused by the binding.